# Having trouble getting data to show correctly in ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
 dbConn.Open()

            Dim Query1 As String = cmbManufacturer.Text
            Dim AccessDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            AccessDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Models.[ModelName] From Models Where Manufacturer = '" & Query1 & "'", dbConn)
            Dim AccessDataset = New DataSet
            AccessDataAdapter.Fill(AccessDataset, "Query1")
            cmbModel.DataSource = AccessDataset.Tables("Query1")

            dbConn.Close()
```

So what this does is, it takes the selection from the manufacturer combo-box and determines the values that will display in the model combo-box

I've seen similar questions like this, but mostly in c# so I'm having trouble relating them.  The problem is the output on the desired combo-box is

> System.Data.DataRowView

when I need it to be the model names that it's pulling from the query.  I changed this from a set of static entries in each combo box to make them dynamic, so in the future we wouldn't need to change the code to add or remove devices from the program.

Comment: try changing cmbModel.datasource to cmbModel.RowSource

Comment: No, it's a windows form.  I'm trying to make an application that interacts with the access database, without users actually having to open access.

Comment: "RowSource is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Combobox"

Comment: Sorry, You need to declare the DisplayMember and the ValueMember 'cmbModel.DisplayMember = "ModelName" ' the same for ValueMember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `.DataSource` is using for filling ComboBox with items, then `DisplayMember` used to retrieve a dipslayed text from the bounded object

From MSDN:

> If the specified property does not exist on the object or the value of
>   DisplayMember is an empty string (""), the results of the object's
>   ToString method are displayed instead.

You are not used `DisplayMember` property, so method `ToString()` was called on the object, which is `System.Data.DataRowView`

You need to set a column name which you want use as displayed text

```
cmbModel.DisplayMember= "ModelName"
'If you will use a SelectedValue for furthers purposes
'Then you maybe want to set a ValueMember too
cmbModel.ValueMember= "ModelName"
cmbModel.DataSource = AccessDataset.Tables("Query1")
```

[DisplayMember Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx)